# Generate Gray Scale Heat Map in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, grayscale

I have a large matrix containing decimal values.
I want to plot a grayscale heat map out of it in Matlab.

How can I do this?

I tried using rgb2gray function but for that I need to create an image first. How can this be done in matlab ?

Comment: Hello Deadman, any followups? You may consider look my answer, I think it solves your question.

Answer (score 4):

`imagesc` will do the job.

```
imagesc(img)
axis equal off
colormap gray
colorbar
```

Comment: Yes, if you have the Image Processing Toolbox, `imshow` works too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `surf`-plot

your Matrix:

```
A = rand(50,50);
```

plot with view from above:

```
surf(A);
view(0,90)
```

the desired grayscale:

```
colormap(gray)
```

and the colorbar as legend:

```
colorbar
```

resulting in:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
myImage = mat2gray(myMatrix); % Converts your data to an image.
figure; hold on; % Creates a figure
imshow(myImage); % Show image
colormap(jet); % Sets the color map you want
colorbar; % Show a color bar on the right
```

Some color maps that may interest you:

jet
[image: jet]

hot [image: hot]

I think `jet` represents a `heatmap`.

More info can be found at [Mathworks colormap page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html).